# Storing return values (void pointers) from malloc

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc, void-pointers

How should I store the `pointer`s returned from `malloc`? I have a small parser that allows nested `include`s in the source files, meaning the first source file can include `foo`, then `foo` can include `bar` and so on.

This feature forces me to keep the memory allocated to each file intact, while opening new files -- therefore allocating new bunch of memory, and keep parsing them until the last file is opened and the last line is parsed, and then I can start `free`ing up the memory from the very last opened file.

The first thing came to my mind was to implementing a *Stack* to keep track of the allocated memory. As I'm doing this for the purpose of learning `C`, I started reading up how can I store returned pointers from `malloc`, however there is so much noise around similar topics like "how to cast `malloc`" that I couldn't find anything helpful.

Then I checked the `malloc` documentation and it says that `malloc` returns `void` pointers, but as far as I know it is generally not recommended to use void pointers as you can't dereference void pointers.

I don't think I need to dereference `malloc` pointers, since I will only need to pass them to the `free` and I shall be fine, however I was wondering if there are any well-known solutions regarding properly storing these pointers in my stack?

The goal is simply to keep track of the allocated memory via stack, so at any moment the pointer to the most recent allocated memory can be poped-out and freed when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use malloc, you are asking for a chunk of memory in which you intend to store something. The malloc function is general-purpose, and neither knows nor cares what type of object you intend to store in the memory it has given you. The pointer-to-void (**void***) return type is the manifestation of malloc's general purpose nature. If, for example, the memory is to contain a big long string of characters, you might choose to accept the pointer into a variable of type **char***. Strong typing forces you to explicitly cast the **void*** to **char***. If you want to create a stack of pointers, then - to continue the example - you would have a stack of **char*** items. The free function takes a pointer to void (**void***), but casting rules say that a pointer to anything can be implicitly cast to a pointer to void, so you can simply pass your **char*** pointer to **free** and it's all good.

Bottom line - as far as malloc is concerned, there is no right or wrong way to store pointers it has returned... it all depends on what you intend to do with the memory; the design of your solution will dictate the optimum approach for handling the pointers.

Comment: No, casting (void *) to any other type does actually _not_ gain any more type-safety. It actually defys that, as it shadows a change in the return type (which is - granted - unlikely for malloc(), but for other functions it might be very well). The standard explicitly allows assigning void * without typecast (and back). This is actually the only operation allowed for void *. Ok, in the second part you got it right

Comment: I was just trying to keep my answer focused on the point of the question. Agreed, casting can get you into trouble, but when you are using malloc, what else are you going to do? At least C++ has **new** to give you allocations in a requested type, but that's a whole other matter.

Comment: @Zenilogix Thanks for the answer. I have `char *`, so I can simply have an array of `char`s and store the pointers, right? and since `void` is the widest available pointer it won't be damaged when I'm passing `char *` to the `free`. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: You need `char *`, not char! And its `void *`; `void` by itself is not a valid datatype for variables. Think of it as "Nothing" (which is different from `NULL` which basically means "invalid"). And yes, `void *` is compatible with other _normal_ pointers. Sidenote ther might be special other pointers for e.g. embedded systems which might have different properties.

Comment: @Mahdi: sorry for being picky, but that helps very much in this field.

Comment: @Olaf No worries, very much appreciate that!

Comment: @Zenilogix: you should not cast `void *` to an actual pointer type. And you don't need toneither does it add to strong typing (C doe not have strong typing, different from e.g. Python). However, it is best practice not to use `void *` for variables, etc. unless there is a good justification. And I don't set this here. (wrote quite similar things back in my days; but I read the files as required; there was just not enough RAM for that - still not sure what the benifit might be, but that is not my project).

Answer (score 1):

You shall not dereference `void *` or use them in expressions with casts. But you can store them as other pointers. However, I suspect you already have assigned them to something like `MyType *myptr = malloc(...)`, so why not store them as `MyType *`? However, if you have a parser and really don't need the memory anymore (that's actually what you wrote), why would you want to keep the memory after all? It would be more efficient to free it once asap. And you do not need an extra structure for them.

If you have problems as the blocks are different types, you might have a look at anonymous structs/unions (since C99), which allow some basic class-derivation, so you can store the objects and process them later without casting. If using gcc, you might also find `-fplan9-extensions` quite appealing (I love those!). This will greatly increase type-safety if used properly. But be aware that you will leave the ISO-path then! (However, use the force).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually need to keep the memory. Imagine I first open the first file, then in the middle of parsing I have to open another file. Here I can't free up the memory that is allocated to the first file, right? Otherwise I won't be able to continue parsing it after finished the included file.

Comment: Ok, so you do _have_ to access the data when stored. Yes, for this a stack would be ok, but you really should store the proper type, Normally it is no good idea to keep `void *` stored somewhere. You should only use it as function arguments/(result) under very well controlled conditions (avoid it whenever possible), but store well-typed pointers. Oh, regarding `char` remember these can be signed or unsigned! This is ok, if you dont use arithmetic operations on them which may yield a negative result.

Comment: Great, so do you recommend `unsigned char` -- given the fact that I'm not gonna do any pointer arithmetic or `char` is enough?

Comment: You should use that type which suits your needs best. If you just have char, that is ok. However, from you question, I would expect you want at least store the text and the index of the current position. This calls for a struct (this might be a good idea anyways, as it can easily be expanded). Remember that C allows to have a flexible array member as the last member. So there is actually no overhead for an extra pointer (and malloc).

Comment: I did not talk about pointer arithmetic. Remember `char` is not a pointer type anyway. No offense, but you might get more comfortable with the notation and semantics if you have problems taking these things apart from each other. (honestly: no offense!)

Comment: oops, I meant arithmetic not pointer arithmetic -- as you mentioned arithmetic operations. I was basically asking if there will be any difference between `char *file_content;` and `unsigned char *file_content;`, followed by `file_content = malloc(file_size + 1);`. P.S. still learning `C`, and definitely make myself confused time to time. Thanks anyways for your time, really appreciate that.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but please understand this is not an online-course. You really should get a good book and possibly read the standard (the final drafts are online for free and can be assumed complete). Sorry I cannot recommend a good book (and this forum is the wrong place to ask), as I learned it decades ago and keep up-to-date rading the standard or searching for specific toppics on the web (most answers are actually here;-). You can do learning by doing; I at least hate artificial lessons without practical background, but get a reference and understand it.